# Can't make a build in Unity using Photon Voice - "plugins colliding with each other"

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking, virtual-reality, voice, photon

Anyone else getting this error when they try to build their scene with Photon voice? Seems to be some issue with the opus_egpv.dll file.

[image]

I've tried it both in my project, attempting to build my main scene, and in a completely empty project with only Photon Voice, attempting to build their demo voice scene.

In both cases I'm unable to finish the build unless I delete the opus_egpv.dll file from the x86_64 folder. 
When I do so, I'm able to run the game successfully for the first user. However, the game will crash for the second user as they try to join in. The second user's game crashes by freezing completely, requiring that I force exit it (this does not affect the first user).

I've tried this with both Unity 2017.3.0f3 and Unity 2017.2.0f3 to the same effect. I'm using the [currently] most recent version of Photon Voice, ver. 1.13 (released Nov 22, 2017). I am making a multiplayer VR game.

Comment: Have you tried running the second build on another machine? And then connect to the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- All files under "Assets\Plugins\x86" should have platforms "Standalone" and "Editor" only and CPU: "X86".
- All files under "Assets\Plugins\x86_64" should have platforms "Standalone" and "Editor" only and CPU: "X86_64".

More information can be found on [the answers to your question on Photon engine forum](http://forum.photonengine.com/discussion/11187/cant-make-a-build-in-unity-using-photon-voice-plugins-colliding-with-each-other#latest).

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks so much for the quick response.